# c# call Oracle' s Procedure Return array

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to Pass an array of string to oracle, and get all no match of those values in database. here is my Proc:

```
    TYPE myArray IS TABLE of varchar(50) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    create or replace PACKAGE BODY TEST AS

      procedure CheckExistL(L IN myArray, lotNotMatch OUT myArray) AS
      j number:=0;
      cnt number :=0;
      BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..L.count LOOP
        select COUNT(*) INTO cnt  FROM myTable 
        WHERE L01 = L(i);
       if (cnt = 0)
       then 

        lotNotmatch(j):=L(i);
        j := j + 1;
       end if;
       END LOOP;

      END CheckExistL;

    END TEST;
and in my C# my code is

               using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    // 
                    cmd.BindByName = true;
                    cmd.ArrayBindCount = myArray.Count();

                    cmd.CommandText = "TEST.CheckExistLPNDetailLottables";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.BindByName = true;
                    OracleParameter P_In = new OracleParameter("L", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
                    P_In.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    P_In.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                    P_In.ArrayBindSize = new int[L.Count()];
                    P_In.Size = myArray.Count();
                    P_In.Value = myArray;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(P_In);

                    OracleParameter P_result = new OracleParameter("lotNotMatch", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
                    P_result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    P_result.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                    P_result.Size = myArray.Count();
                    P_result.ArrayBindSize = new int[myArray.Count()];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(P_result);
                    cmd.Parameters["L"].Value = myArray;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var arrNotMatch = cmd.Parameters["lotNotMatch"].Value;
                    }
```

I don't get any error compilation and when is excuteNonQuery I get an error from Oracle:
ORA-06513: PL/SQL: index for PL/SQL table out of range for host language array
ORA-06512: at line 1
Which one is out of range? some reference in web mentioned to add maxRowsSize, but I couldn't find it in cmd, or parameter properties.

Comment: It seems array in Oracle starts from 1, try changing `j number:=1;`

Comment: Thanks Vijai, Now i'm getting another error:
compile bind length different from execute bind length

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it compiled, But please test it.

```
CREATE TYPE myArray AS TABLE of varchar(50);
create or replace procedure CheckExistL(L IN myArray, lotNotMatch OUT myArray) AS
      j number:=1;
      cnt number :=0;
  BEGIN
      lotNotMatch := new myArray();
      lotNotMatch.EXTEND(L.count);

        FOR i IN 1..L.count 
        LOOP
          select COUNT(*) INTO cnt  FROM myTable 
          WHERE L01 = L(i);

          if (cnt = 0)   then 
            lotNotmatch(j):=L(i);
            j := j + 1;
          end if;
       END LOOP;

END CheckExistL;
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
Error(7,24): PLS-00222: no function with name 'MYARRAY' exists in this scope